# Vue как реализовать timeline цен?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas

подскажите есть ли готовые решение для решение этой задачи, нужно сделать вот такую таблицу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные приходят с сервера:

```
schedule_date_start: data - начало
schedule_date_end: data - конец
price: integer - цена
```

Comment: chart.js юзай  и  сделаеш как душе угодно

Comment: chart.js как я знаю свои графики. И там нет такого или я ошибаюсь?